# Selective parsing of matrix rows

Tags: matrix, pixelandtonic

I am using matrix to pull instagram photos using the pic puller plugin. Sometimes, the picture is not available. I am able to skip these by using an if conditional in the pic puller loop. however an empty matrix row is still parsed and shown on the final template. I am not sure how to just show the rows with instagram content.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="mychannel" status="open" }
    {matrix_field} 

        {exp:ig_picpuller:media user_id="1" media_id="{media_id}" use_stale_cache="yes"}
        {if ig_status == "true"}
            {ig_standard_resolution}
        {/if}
        {/exp:ig_picpuller:media}

    {/matrix_field}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

I considered using the ig_status tag as a search parameter in matrix, but didn't work.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="mychannel" status="open" }
    {exp:ig_picpuller:media user_id="1" media_id="{media_id}" use_stale_cache="yes"}

        {matrix_field search:{ig_status}="true"} 
                {ig_standard_resolution}
        {/matrix_field}

    {/exp:ig_picpuller:media}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Any ideas how i can skip the rows without any pictures from being parsed?

Comment: Why doesn't your first code example work? Just keep all of your markup for the row inside of the `{if ig_status == "true"}` conditional, so nothing will show for that row if there's no photo.

Comment: The pic puller tags depends on the {media_id} variable from the matrix field. So can't wrap the matrix tags with the pic puller conditional. I tried using nsm transplant to retrieve the media_ids within the conditional ( only rows with actual pictures ), then use it as a search parameter in the matrix field ( hence limiting it to parse only rows with actual pictures. That seemed to work - ( only rows with pictures showed up).  But the row count variable was off - it still shows the count of each row with the excluded rows.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting wrapping the Matrix tags inside the conditional - but just everything you want to *do* with the Matrix tags (i.e., your markup). Another Q: what is `media_id` - a text input? When you ay "sometimes the picture is not available", why is that? Bad `media_id`? Timeout on Instagram's end? Or *no* `media_id` at all?

Comment: media_id is a text input column in matrix. the pic puller plugin uses that to  pull the pictures from instagram. Sometimes, the original picture on instagram is deleted - hence not available. so the media_id exists just no picture. when there is no picture, pic puller has a field called "ig_status" which registers as "false". hence the conditional.  I am not following what you mean with the wrap. can you give me a quick code example?

Comment: I mean: put *all* of your markup and code for each Matrix row inside of `{if ig_status == "true"}` - even the stuff which might not be related to the photo itself. This way, you're displaying nothing at all for that row when there's no photo. You have the same issue with the `row_count` being off of course - but there's no alternative to that really. You can't filter a query by the result of an operation within that query.

Comment: Sorry but still confused. How is this different from the first code block I have? All of my mark up is inside the conditional. i showed {ig_standard_resolution} here just as an example of what I am pulling for the final output. but there is a whole lot of other stuff in there - all related to variables for pic puller.

Comment: It's only different in that you've obviously simplified your example, and I'm suggesting that in your real template code, you place *everything* inside of that conditional. Is there a reason that doesn't work?

Comment: what is "everything" ? that is where I am getting hung up. note that pic puller requires the media_id variable from matrix ( hence has to be placed inside the matrix tags)

Comment: "Everything" is presumably the HTML markup which surrounds your photo, or any other data you might be using in your Matrix field. In your q you say "an empty Matrix field is shown on the final template" - so I assume you have markup which is placed outside of the pic puller conditional which is showing even when there is no photo found. In which case, move all that inside the conditional.

Comment: Ok - All of my markup relating to rendering the pictures are already in the ig_status conditional as stated earlier . There is nothing outside . The empty matrix row is shown for rows within the conditional where the original picture is no longer available . My q is looking for ways to prevent matrix rows within the conditional not to be parsed if no picture is available . Does this help?

Comment: No - as I mentioned before, you can't filter a query by the result of an operation within that query's result. You'd have to process the Matrix field twice - the first time checking for the picture and storing the `row_id` somehow if it's there, then a second time pulling only those previously-saved `row_id`s. Maybe Stash could help?

Comment: Interesting - didn't know I could embed a matrix tag pair in another matrix tag pair. I tried using stash and nsm transplant. I got nsm transplant to work  ( only rows with good media_ids were returned - no empty rows ), but the row_count was still off. still showed the original row count.

Comment: To clarify - I'm not talking about *embedding* a Matrix field within another. I'm talking about parsing the same field twice in the same template - the first time just to figure out which rows are "good", then somehow storing that info and reusing to filter the 2nd instance of the same Matrix field with  your collected row_ids.

Comment: got it. will give it a shot. many thxx!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming ig_status is a column in the Matrix field, you don't want the curlies in the search:col_name="" parameter:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="mychannel" status="open" }
{exp:ig_picpuller:media user_id="1" media_id="{media_id}" use_stale_cache="yes"}

    {matrix_field search:ig_status="true"} 
            {ig_standard_resolution}
    {/matrix_field}

{/exp:ig_picpuller:media}
```

{/exp:channel:entries}

Comment: Unfortunately, {ig_status} is not a matrix field. Rather it is a field from the pic puller plugin.  I guess I can't use an external field as a parameter in matrix?   Generally how can i turn off rows based on an external parameter?

Comment: Also, {media_id} is a matrix field - which is a required parameter in the pic puller tag.